# Xcode - How do you create an Activity Feed?

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I'm having an issue finding information on creating an activity feed in Xcode. I am new to developing so I'm trying to find something that really breaks things down. I'm looking to create a feed similar to twitter. Does any one know what my first steps should be? or at least a tutorial I could be referred to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well an activity feed is at its heart a *list* of "posts". So first learn how to make lists. Act I is making a `UITableView` with custom cells.

For the basics, see [this tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/) and Apple's own [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1). If you want a book, I recommend the Big Nerd Ranch book "[iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th Edition](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/ios-programming.html)". Chapter 8 is all about `UITableView`.

Ignore the default Apple layouts, which don't look much like an activity feed yet. Once you get past the basics you'll make your own cells.

Once you've mastered the basics, focus on custom cells, as the Apple defaults won't cut it for your hot new activity feed. Here's a tutorial for [custom cells](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

Ray Wenderlich also has a pretty in depth series of articles you can use to drill deeper in any specific areas of interest: [UITableView articles](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview).

Then, you've got to get data into your newsfeed somehow. This is Act II. Presumably this will begin as JSON from a REST web service. So you need to connect to a web server, parse JSON, and get Objective-C classes out the other side, ready to pass to your table view.

Learn the [basics of Cocoapods](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2), then use it to install [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) and [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle).

Use AFNetworking to retrieve JSON from whatever URL, then use Mantle to parse it. I found this tutorial useful for [getting started with Mantle](http://substantial.com/blog/2014/05/20/parsing-json-in-ios-with-mantle/).

After that, you should have your first activity feed!